# Unable to Download Wine due to Update Error?

Tags: 16.04, wine, repository, playonlinux

I'm looking for a way to successfully run Age of Empires II on my chromebook. I'm using xenial currently and have tried every which way to make Wine work, but with no success. My issue seems to be after I add the repository, I update before downloading Wine2.0, but I get a whole lot of error messages which I think is causing the problem. Unfortunately I have no coding experience whatsoever so i don't really no what it means. Anyway, when I input

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get in return

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease
Err:4 https://dl/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: dl
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages    
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1189 B]
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:14 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B] 
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Hit:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Fetched 2008 B in 2s (767 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1397BC53640DB551
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch https://dl/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: dl
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is really bugging me as I've been fighting with it for a few days now, and I just want to be able to use PlayOnLinux to launch AoEII. P.S. I know there's an easier way to paste a lot of code but I couldn't figure it out so i just put 4 spaces in front of every line. If someone could enlighten me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Try following the steps specified [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/11/wine-2-21-released-how-to-install-it-via-ppa/)  .

Comment: @daumie the PPA has been deprecated - Wine has their own upstream repos now.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ThomasWard , that was the last repo I personally used and everything worked.

Comment: @daumie FWIW, the issue is OP typoed entering the URL for Wine's repos.  :)

Comment: @daumie I tried using the steps that you linked however, still running into issues. I also went in and fixed my broken repositories but it was no help. Still getting those pesky errors when I 'sudo apt-get update'. Don't know where to go from here as I've tried fixing with aptitude, using a variety of package fixing methods. Losing all hope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) and [How to fix not signed repos which worked before?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036130/)

Answer (score 1):

For Wine specifically, the repository URL you entered is wrong.

`https://dl/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease` is incorrect.

`https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease` is correct.

You need to go find where you added the repository and fix it.  Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and every `.list` file within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to find the invalid URL and update it.

---

You also have a 404 Not Found issue with the Ubuntu Repository mirror you're using; to fix that, you might need to use a different mirror than `ports.ubuntu.com`.