# How to fix not signed repos which worked before?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, jenkins

on an Ubuntu 16.04 server I get the following messages when running `sudo apt-get update`:

> E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable
>   Release' is no longer signed. N: Updating from such a repository can't
>   be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details. E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   xenial-security Release' is no longer signed. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details. W: The repository
>   'http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' is not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore
>   potentially dangerous to use. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
>   repository creation and user configuration details.

The server is behind a proxy which works, for example I ran `wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -` and it just printed *OK*. But when running `sudo apt-get update` the same errors as shown above are printed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it with the help of [dino99](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391947). The Google and Jenkins repositories needed https. To fix the Security repository I replaced `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release` with `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse`.
Not sure what the exact issue is, but it worked.